# Is there a short Lambda expression for a->a->Ordering?

Tags: haskell, lambda, anonymous-function

Lambda Expressions can make life easier and I love the way, you can shorten expressions like `(\x -> x + 1)` to `(+1)`.

That's why I'm wondering if there is anything similar for anonymous functions that take two arguments and return a `Ordering`.

For example: Can you shorten this code:

```
sortByFirst :: Ord a => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
sortByFirst = sortBy (\x y -> fst x `compare` fst y)
```

Comment: `sortByFirst = sortOn fst`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `on` function, from the `Data.Function` module.

```
import Data.List

sortByFirst = sortBy (compare `on` fst)
```

The definition of `on` is roughly

```
on f g = \x y -> f (g x) (g y)
```

Comment: Even sweeter: with `comparing` from `Data.Ord`, `sortByFirst = sortBy (comparing fst)`

Comment: Oops, forgot about that specific function.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Jere, `sortOn` is less efficient than the `sortByFirst` defined in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

With `comparing` from `Data.Ord`, it can be spelled as...

```
sortByFirst = sortBy (comparing fst)
```

... which is equivalent to is equivalent to the `` compare `on` fst `` in [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53491426/2751851).

(`Data.List` also offers a `sortOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]`, but that is a special purpose function which is only worth using if the involved `a -> b` function is somewhat expensive, something that `fst` is not.)