# How to generate the cartesian join of a list of tuples based on their first value?

Tags: haskell

I have a list of tuple of type `(Int,String)` and i want to generate a list of type `[String]` in which each string is a cartesian join permutation of second elements of the tuples that have the same `Int` value. For example:

input: `[(1,"abc"),(1,"def"),(2,"ghi"),(2,"kl")]`

output: `["ad", "ae", "af", "bd", "be", "bf", "cd", "ce", "cf", "gk", "gl", "hk", "hl", "ik", "il"]`

I tried this but i can't find a way of just permuting the tuples with the same `Int` value:

```
possible_keys :: [(Int,String)] -> [String]
possible_keys subkeys = [ key | keysize <- keysizes, key<-keys]
  where keysizes = map (fst) subkeys
        keys = sequence (map (snd) subkeys)
```

Any hint?

Comment: @duplode if there is just one tuple , that tuple is ignored . if there's more than 2 tuples with the same int value like in your exampe it would give ["adx", "ady","adz","aex","aey","ayz","afx","afy","afz","bex","bey"...]

Comment: That's fine -- I had looked only at your example, and didn't notice you were already fine with using `sequence` for the permutations.

Comment: yeah it is cycling ok but i still can't find a way of filtering the permutations with other tuples rather than those with the same int value

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy) to keep the groups of tuples apart:

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.List

possible_keys :: Ord k => [(k, [c])] -> [[c]]
possible_keys = concat . fmap sequenceA . fmap (fmap snd)
    . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sortBy (comparing fst)
```

(I'm assuming the input list isn't necessarily sorted. I'm sorting by the keys alone to make it minimally invasive. `comparing fst` is the same as `` compare `on` fst ``; unfortunately there isn't an analogous `equating` in the standard library yet. `sequenceA` is the same as `sequence`, [only more general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40181158/2751851).)

This can be slimmed down a bit. The second functor law allows us to combine consecutive uses of `fmap`:

```
possible_keys :: Ord k => [(k, [c])] -> [[c]]
possible_keys = concat . fmap (sequenceA . fmap snd)
    . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sortBy (comparing fst)
```

`fmap` followed by `sequenceA` is `traverse`:

```
possible_keys :: Ord k => [(k, [c])] -> [[c]]
possible_keys = concat . fmap (traverse snd)
    . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sortBy (comparing fst)
```

Finally, `fmap` followed by `concat` on a list is `concatMap` (or `(=<<)`, but that would be a little too cryptic here):

```
possible_keys :: Ord k => [(k, [c])] -> [[c]]
possible_keys = concatMap (traverse snd)
    . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sortBy (comparing fst)
```

Note that this will generate strings of length one for keys with just one tuple -- `sequenceA ["abc"]` is `["a","b","c"]`. If you don't want that, you can `filter` the groups of tuples immediately after the `groupBy` to get rid of those with just one tuple.

Comment: there's also [`sortOn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn) now. I wonder if it's smart enough to not do the whole decorate-undecorate thing for such simple accessors as `fst`, though. Probably not.

Comment: @WillNess Last time I tried to use `sortOn` here, [dfeuer told us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53491403/is-there-a-short-lambda-expression-for-a-a-ordering/53572182#comment94656383_53491426) that performance-wise it is only worth using if the projection function you give to it is expensive. (As you note in your edited comment.)

Comment: yeah, thought of it in the mean time. :) that's unfortunate; the more detail a programmer needs to concern  themself with, the worse. I'm a radical here; I'd like to see a language with e.g. sequences, where the compiler itself would choose lists or trees or arrays or whatever, as needed. (I'm not building it though...:) ).

Comment: @WillNess Unfortunate indeed. I kind of feel the "sortOn" name is too inviting for such a special-purpose function...

Comment: @WillNess, duplode, there is a function that does the job, but it's buried in `GHC.Exts`: `sortWith`.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks for the pointer. And there is a sorting `groupWith` there as well!

Comment: @dfeuer, duplode thanks. but, when an accessor is heavy, the decorate-sort-undecorate transform is too important to forgo for a few keystrokes. turns out `groupWith` uses `sortWith`, which is just a shorter way to key in `sortBy . comparing`.